# $2\times 2$ block Toeplitz determinant

Tags: matrices, asymptotics, determinant, block-matrices

My question is about computing asymptotic the determinant (dimension of the matrix $n\to\infty$) of a $2\times 2$ block Toeplitz matrix.
$$\mbox{det}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
a_n & b_n \\
d_n & e_n  \end{array} \right)$$
where $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ and $d_n$ are Toeplitz matrices. To illustrate the meaning of a Toeplitz matrix, you can have a look to the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix

I know that in the scalar case, the determinant can be computed by using the Szegö's theorems https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Szeg%C3%B6_limit_theorems 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mbox{det}(T_n(\alpha))=\left(G(\alpha)\right)^n E(\alpha)
\end{equation}
The dominant term at big dimension, $G$, can be easily extended to the matritial case as $G(\alpha)=\exp[(\log(\mbox{det}\;\alpha ))_0]$. However, I found no close expression for the correction $E(\alpha)$.

Is there any way to extend these theorems to the matritial case? I am interested on analytic or semi-analytic expressions. However, if it is not possible, numerical solutions, factorizations or simplifications are also welcomed. Thanks for any help!

Note: The symbol has in general no symmetries that would lead to a simplification of the problem, i.e.
$$  T_n=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
a_n & b_n \\
d_n & e_n  \end{array} \right) $$
where $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ and $d_n$ are in general independent.

Comment: The extension to block Toeplitz matrices has a paragraph on the linked page, in the paragraph on H. Widom's contributions to the subject.

Comment: As far as I know, Widom made some important extensions to the matritial case under some special conditions. However, I am worry that my problem doesn't fulfill these conditions. I was more looking for further analytical extensions in this direction, any numerical method or some approximation that would help me to deal with the problem.

Comment: In that case, you might want to add some details regarding the kind of block Toeplitz symbol you're using. My own sense is that, if one just wants the leading asymptotic results, then Widom's results are sufficient. It's the corrections which are hard (and which I personally would like to know more about). For some example results, check out this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0607065.pdf) by Basor and Erhardt especially section 2.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Semiclassical, I have included your suggestions to my question. With respect to the preprint you posted, it is interesting but devoted to a special case where the block entries follow some condition. In my problem the blocks are independent in general.